# Send direct messages with twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm working on a twitter bot with the twitter gem. This bot is liking and following peoples. But now i want to send private messages with this gem and i cant.

This is what Im testing :

```rb
def login_twitter_stream
  client_streaming =
    Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
      config.access_token = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
    end
  return client_streaming
end

def login_twitter
  client_REST =
    Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
      config.access_token = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
    end
  return client_REST
end

def direct_messages
  client = login_twitter

  client
    .search("#helloworld", result_type: "recent")
    .take(5)
    .each do
      client.create_direct_message(
        "#{tweet.user}",
        "hello this is a test!",
        options = {}
      )
    end
end

direct_messages
```

And this is the error I have with a simple

```rb
client.create_direct_message("@username","hello this is a test!",options={})
```

```rb
event.message_create.target.recipient_id: '@username' is not a valid Long (Twitter::Error::BadRequest)
```

ans this one:

```rb
undefined local variable or method `tweet' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I hope u have the solution ! Have a great day.

Comment: "not a valid long" sounds like the function is expecting a user ID (numeric) instead of a username (string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the id of the twitter you want to send a message with. You can use this [link](http://gettwitterid.com/) to get an Id.

Then you can execute the command:

```
client.create_direct_message('<replace with the twitter Id you obtained>',"hello this is a test!",options={})
```

the tweet.user in your example means, there is a tweets-table(a model class) and the twitter Id is saved in the user-column.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)